# Sympy not showing expected answer

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import Sum,I,pi,exp,oo
from sympy.abc import k

A0 = 12
f0 = 50

def c(k):
    if k%2==0:
        return 2*A0/(pi * (1- k**2))
    else:
        return 0

def x(t):
    expr1 = Sum(c(k)*exp(2*I*pi*k*f0*t),(k,-oo,oo))
    return(expr1.doit())
```

Above code is returning 0 for every t for x(t) but it shouldn't do that.What I wanted is Fourier Series of A|sin2pif0t|

Comment: I suspect that `k % 2` never evaluates to `0` given that `k` is a symbol & not an integer, so `c(k)` will always return `0`

Comment: I agree with DrBwts. What you need is `sympy.core.mod.Mod`. You can find its documentation here: [sympy.core.mod.Mod](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=modulo#sympy.core.mod.Mod)

Comment: I tried replacing k with other variable(not imported from sympy.abc) and still got same. As @DrBwts and @Invarianz said, I tried using `sympy.core.mod.Mod` but still got same.

Answer (score 0):

You need a symbolic conditional expression:

```
In [95]: c = Piecewise((2*A0/(pi * (1- k**2)), Eq(k%2, 0)), (0, True))

In [96]: c
Out[96]: 
⎧    24                     
⎪──────────  for k mod 2 = 0
⎪  ⎛     2⎞                 
⎨π⋅⎝1 - k ⎠                 
⎪                           
⎪    0          otherwise   
⎩
```

Unfortunately SymPy still cannot compute the summation in closed form (it might be impossible):

```
In [97]: s = Sum(c*exp(2*I*pi*k*f0*t),(k,-oo,oo)).doit()

In [98]: s
Out[98]: 
  ∞                                     
______                                  
╲                                       
 ╲                                      
  ╲    ⎧    100⋅ⅈ⋅π⋅k⋅t                 
   ╲   ⎪24⋅ℯ                            
    ╲  ⎪───────────────  for k mod 2 = 0
    ╱  ⎨     ⎛     2⎞                   
   ╱   ⎪   π⋅⎝1 - k ⎠                   
  ╱    ⎪                                
 ╱     ⎩       0            otherwise   
╱                                       
‾‾‾‾‾‾                                  
k = -∞
```